# How to access a tag which inside the header

Tags: c#, .net

I want to access a tag inside the header from the C# code.
I want to check "IF" condition and for one result disable the visibility of the tag and in other to send to another page.
the following code:

```asp
<header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="float-left">
            <p class="site-title">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~\Images\AssetManagementIcon.PNG" Style="background-color: transparent; border: none;" Height="67px" Width="242px" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="float-right">
            <section id="login">
            </section>
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Log Out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

    </div>
</header>
```

I want to get access to the  `<li><a runat="server" href="~/">Log Out</a></li>`.

Comment: a is not an asp control. so, it can't be accessed directly from codebehind. You can use hyperlink instead

Comment: So if i change it to hyperlink, how can i access it from C# ?

Comment: I think he meant a hyperlink to a logoff page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using asp.net and as you wrote you want to access the Log out tag.
I would suggest that you use the asp.net hyperlink. you could use your code as it's but you need to add an ID so you can call it in your javascript but it would be cleaner with a hyperlink like this i would recommend.

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hpLogout" runat="server">Log Out</asp:HyperLink>
```

You could also put your text inside the hyperlink control like:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hpLogout" runat="server" Text="Log Out" />
```

but it's the same as the previous one.

You could on the other hand put your function inside your hyperlink tag like

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hpLogout" runat="server" Text="Log Out" OnClick="MyFunction" />
```

Of course MyFunction is your already defined function in c# codebehind.

and again all you need is a ID that you can call to validate with youron the codebehind for your C# code.

I hope this will help you.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Put an id to the '' tag. Do as following...

```
<header>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a id="aID" runat="server" href="~/">Log Out</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

And access it from code behind using it's id...

```
aID.InnerText = "hello";
```